# How to create multiple counts in a mysql statement

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have some trouble to count more than 2 counts in mysql statement.

My   `count(b.entry_id) as totalbooking` wont work. What have i done wrong? Is the statement setup also correctly made​​?

This is how i tried:

```
"SELECT 
    t.restaurant_id as restaurant_id, ct.title as title, 
    count(DISTINCT t.cardid) as totalmembers, 
    count(t.restaurant_id) as totaltransactions, 
    count(b.entry_id) as totalbooking
    from transactions as t   
    inner join exp_menucard_booking as b on (t.restaurant_id = b.entry_id)
    inner join exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
    inner JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
    where t.cardid != 88888888 and ct.status = 'open'
    group by t.restaurant_id
    order by ct.title asc";
```

Comment: What do you mean with don't work?

Comment: count(b.entry_id) as totalbooking wont count. Everything else is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern to count subsets of the total rowset:

```
sum( case when ColumnToBeTested = trueCondition then 1 else 0 end) as SubCount
```